# Firebase hosting failing to deploy angular material app

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-hosting

I created a angular material app and didnt really add code yet. on running locally it shows the page just fine. now when i try to deploy it to firebase hosting it gets deployed. however, opening the page shows the standard message that setup is done but nothing really deployed.

the firebase.json file looks like below

```
{
  "functions": {
    "source": "functions",
    "predeploy": "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run build"
  },
  "database": {
    "rules": "database.rules.json"
  },
  "hosting": {
    "public": "dist/kubby-web",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  },
  "storage": {
    "rules": "storage.rules"
  }
}
```

and i am trying to access it at:
https://trykubby-1.web.app/

I have no idea what is wrong.

by the way data is already there in the dist/kubby-web as a result of ng build.

```
moblizeit@macbook-pro-91 kubby-web % pwd
public/kubby-web/dist/kubby-web
moblizeit@macbook-pro-91 kubby-web % ls
3rdpartylicenses.txt        favicon.ico         index.html          main.91e79c7a9b1b2467.js    polyfills.edb904453eb39932.js   runtime.5f99f1e58982b7fc.js styles.c590233c6e1776c4.css
```

Answer (score 0):

Check that the `public` folder actually holds the website and not the placeholder website. Adjust `public` to the actual build target folder.

`"public": "dist/kubby-web",`

Comment: that is not the case. see the updated question for results

Comment: @VivekK  Is `dist/kubby-web/index.html` showing your app code or the default page?

Comment: default page. https://trykubby-1.web.app/dist/kubby-web/index.html